# how can i assign data which is from custom configuration sections to a global variable in mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Below code is an object am creating to get values from custom config section which is secureAppSettings

```
NameValueCollection section = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("secureAppSettings");
```

using this object if  i try to assign it to global variable like

```
public static string ServerName = section["ServerName"];
```

It is showing error like

A field initializer cannot reference the non static field.

How can i assign it to a global variable

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share bit more code of the class?

Comment: you either have to make `section` static too, or you need an instance of your class to access it.

Comment: Thanks casiosmu, It works when i make section as static... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an instance variable to initialize another instance variable. Why? Because the compiler can rearrange these - there is no guarantee that reminder will be initialized before defaultReminder, so the above line might throw a NullReferenceException.